# How can I make a function to select all in a Flex textbox?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, components

I'm trying to create a simple "smart" textbox component in Flex, and I want a function inside it that I can use outside of the component to force itself to select all text inside of it.

Inside my `SmartTextbox.mxml`:

```
public function selectAll():void
{
    this.setSelection(0, this.length);
}
```

I also use this function when the textbox gets focus, like this:

```
private function onTextInput_focusIn(event:Event):void
{
        selectAll();
}
```

The later one, on focusIn event, is working.
But if I try to call the function from outside, like:

Inside another component where `texInputQuickSearch` is a SmartTextBox-component.

```
if(searchModule.currentState == SearchModule.STATE_SEARCH)
{
    doSearch();
    searchModule.textInputQuickSearch.selectAll();              
}
```

It won't reselect the text.

Why does it work like this?

Comment: with a debuggeur , or by putting a log do you see if  selectAll() is executed in the texInputQuickSearch context ?

Comment: Do you throws any exception in doSearch() ?

Comment: Are you by any chance setting selectable property to false?

Comment: With the debugger I can see that the selectAll is executed, but directly after it has executed the selectionBeginIndex and selectionEndIndex are still at the same as before = no selection.

And the selectAll works when I execute it on the focusIn event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something similar to this...

AS3:

```
import mx.core.UITextField;

private function initializeHandler( event:Event ):void{

  var ti:TextInput = event.currentTarget as TextInput;
  var tf:UITextField = ti.mx_internal::getTextField();

  tf.alwaysShowSelection = true;

  ti.setFocus();
}


private function setSelection( start:int, end:int ):void{

  txtName.selectionBeginIndex = start;
  txtName.selectionEndIndex = end;
```

}

MXML:

```
<mx:TextInput id="txtName"
  initialize="initializeHandler( event );"/>
```

Comment: It worked! :) Thank you, mind explaining why it worked? I'm not familiar with mx_internal and the UITextField component.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that your conditional statement is not evaluating to TRUE when you expect it to.  Maybe it's a typo in your question but you have:

searchModule with a lowercase "s" compared to SearchModule with an uppercase "S"

If you're not using Flex Builder or someother debug environment, I would test it with a trace or something inside the true code block like this (which can be run from inside the FLASH IDE):

```
if(searchModule.currentState == SearchModule.STATE_SEARCH) {
    trace("made it here...I'm in");
    doSearch();
    searchModule.textInputQuickSearch.selectAll();
    trace("you should have seen it select!");
}
```

Verify that both outputs print.  If so, you at least know that doSearch() isn't getting stuck.

Comment: I use SearchModule.STATE_SEARCH because it's a static state-name.